Using Chartkick to create a scatter_plot for pairs of datetimes
I am running Ruby 3.3.1, Rails 7.1.3 and Chartkick 5.0.7.
I have a model called Modela, with two fields: date1:date and datetime1:datetime.
I would like Chartkick to generate a scatter_chart, where the x-axis is the date as per date1, and the y-axis is the time component of datetime1.
Here is what I have:
<%= scatter_chart Modela.all.pluck(:date1, :datetime1), xmin: "2024-01-01", xmax: "2024-07-01" %>

Ultimately, I'd like the range for the x-axis to be the range of all date1's, and I'd like the range for the y-axis to be 00:00 at the bottom to 23:59 at the top.
I can't get any further than this:

It's making the range way to high on each axis. Not only that, but when I mouse over the one dot, it gives values all of "2024", which makes me suspect it is only reading the year component of each field.
Is there any way to get the behaviour I want?

Lokking at the docs for Chartkick, I don't think the scatter plot accepts time series. https://github.com/ankane/chartkick/blob/v5.0.7/vendor/assets/javascripts/chartkick.js#L2476

Dang, looks like you're right.
Thanks for checking that out, looks like I'll have to try something else.
